# Upgrading to PT 10 or stay on PT 9

Tags: pro-tools-9, pro-tools-10

Hi there,

I am in a bit of a conundrum. I teach at a film school where we are currently working on PT 9 with 2 MAC's on PT10. I do have the opportunity to upgrade to PT 11 but with all the negative reports floating about I am quite apprehensive to upgrade until I know the system is stable and will accommodate all the plug-in's etc. But I have also read up on PT 10 and there are also issues with this system as well- plug-in upgrades not working, cost of upgrading etc.

I am still nervous about spending money on a system that will not accommodate what I have on the existing PT 9.

What are your experiences and what do you think are the risks involved in upgrading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest waiting until the software gets appropriate bug fixes, if you don't have immediate needs for upgrading.

> what do you think are the risks involved in upgrading?

Wasting time on fighting with incomplete software. Not getting work done.

> I am still nervous about spending money on a system that will not accommodate what I have on the existing PT 9.

So there's no backwards compatibility or is it broken in PT11? Or was this the case of dropping RTAS/TDM? If it's the case of dropping RTAS/TDM, then I would not upgrade (possibly at all), because it's possible that AAX versions will not be available or that they won't be provided free of cost. And well, everyone can see that it's just part of Avid's yet another cash cow plan.